# how should be the resources name while am doing localization

Tags: wpf, resources, naming-conventions

May I know how should be the resource names while doing localization, whether it's should be as Resources.en-US.resx or Resources.en.resx, which one best practice? and why?

Comment: sorry Resources.en-US.resx or Resources.en.resx

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the appropiate culture code append to the resource file name as like below

"Resources.en-US.resx"

Please refer below the link,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa992030.aspx